# Add item to style in head from a div before style is used

Tags: jquery, css, base64, background-image

So the situation is I have my style set up in the head like this:

```
<style>
    .img_png_1 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: -20px -80px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

I have then downloaded an image as base64 code, and thrown it into a div:

```
<div id="backgroundImage">
    base 64 code will be here
</div>
```

This code was loaded by an ajax call. So once it is down, I want to then make this image the background for the style. The catch is that the div that will contain the background image is not yet created. If it was, I could do something like:

```
$(".img_png_1").css("background-image", "url('data:image/png;base64," + $("#backgroundImage").text() + "')");
```

to get the background image into the div (I have not tested this yet as it is not what I want anyhow), but this would only work for already loaded divs.

I want to load this code into the style for all future use when a div with that class is created. I tried a few things with append, but then I can only write an entire style, not append to a particular style.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem with writing a new style tag? What does `all future use` mean?

Comment: The problem with writing a new tag is that I would loose everything in the current tag, I just need to add the one item to that particular style. All future use means that if I create a div down the track with this style, than the changes I have made to the style would be reflected in that div. Using JQueries .css() makes a change to every div with that style, not the actual style. So if you create a div with that style down the track, it will not have the changes applied to it.

Comment: `would lose everything in current tag`...no...that's not true. No big deal adding another style tag. Its just going to be part of the `cascade` which is what the `c` in css stands for

Comment: Good point! I can just have 2 .class_name tags in the style. Seems to work well, although it is a bit messy, will do the trick for now. I will update with an answer until someone comes up with a better suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, at the moment, the problem has been solved, although I'm not sure if there is a better answer than this out there.

So what I did (thanks to charlietfl) was to append an extra style with the same name:

```
$("head > style").append(".img_png_1 { background-image: url('data:image/png;base64," + $("#backgroundImage").text() + "'); }");
```

This will then create a second style with the same name, and when using chrome dev tools etc (not source code), you will see this appear with all the code in it. I then added the required div and it showed as required.